# How to secure knockout template?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using next piece of code to load templates dynamical:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#templateContainer").load("templates.html");
    }
```

Is there any way template content can be secure from public load?
I am using ASP.NET MVC etc.

Comment: Do you really need to protect your view? Isnt the data that needs protection? If that is fine, you can use my lib to get the templates. https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.TemplateStore/wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a physical file create an action that will return your template in a view. You can use `AuthorizeAttribute` or any other means to secure your action.

Than replace `template.html` with an url pointing to your action.

Comment: You mean to return template content using MVC view + use of AuthorizeAttribute ? Good option, thank you